# C Slope finder returning weird numbers

Tags: c

In C, I am attempting to create a program which finds slope in an effort to learn more about it as a language. I have created 6 variables to hold the needed information:

```
//variables

int one_x;
int one_y;

int two_x;
int two_y;

float top_number;
float bottom_number;
```

Then, I created a way for the user to enter the information.

```
printf("------------------\n");

printf("Enter the first x coordinate.\n");
printf(">>>  \n");
scanf("%d", &one_x);

printf("Enter the first y coordinate.\n");
printf(">>>  \n");
scanf("%d", &one_y);


printf("------------------\n");

printf("Enter the second x coordinate.\n");
printf(">>>  \n");
scanf("%d", &two_x);

printf("Enter the second y coordinate.\n");
printf(">>>  \n");
scanf("%d", &two_y);
```

Lastly, the program solves the problem  and displays the answer.

```
bottom_number = two_x-one_x;

top_number = two_y - one_y;

printf ("The Slope is %d/%d", top_number, bottom_number);
```

But, whenever it is run it returns strange numbers:

```
1606415936/1606415768
```

Why is this?

I am using xcode and `#include <stdio.h>`

Comment: 1. what are the numbers you enter? 2. top and bottom number are floats

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`top_number` and `bottom_number` are declared as `float` but you try to print them as `int` (the `%d` format specifier tells `printf` to interpret an argument as type `int`).  `int` and `float` have different sizes and bit representations so this doesn't work.

There are a number of options to fix this.  You could change them to `int`

```
int top_number;
int bottom_number;
```

or change the format specifiers in your final `printf` to `%f`

```
printf ("The Slope is %f/%f", top_number, bottom_number);
```

or cast the values in your `printf`

```
printf ("The Slope is %d/%d", (int)top_number, (int)bottom_number);
```

Note that there is no benefit in using `float` unless you may need to represent a fraction.  This isn't possible here as you're subtracting two `int`s.  A calculation of the slope (`top_number/bottom_number`) should however be treated as `float`.

Finally, as hmjd earlier mentioned, you should really check the return value from `scanf` to make sure you have actually read an `int` after each call

```
while (scanf("%d", &one_y) != 1);
// repeat this pattern for each scanf call
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using printf to display floats using the integer placeholder %d. You need to use %f to display floats.

But...why do you need floats here? You are subtracting integers, so your answers will be integers. Change the type of top_number and bottom_number to int.

Still won't be perfect as your displayed "fraction" won't be reduced to it's minimal form, but that's another project, right?